# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I am extracting results from a database and everything works fine except this line which gives me an error for every result.

Basically I have an `<area>` of the same `coords` as every `<polygon>`'s points of my `<svg>` and I'm trying to update the polygon's `fill-opacity` when I hover the area.

```
document.getElementById('TEST_area').onmouseenter=function(){ document.getElementById('TEST').style.fill-opacity = '0.5;'; };
```

I really don't know what happened here, because at some point it worked.

The coords are not a problem, they work, because whenever I click on my areas, I get the response I want. But not for `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`

Thank you.

Comment: `'".$row['regionname']."_area'` is an invalid string literal

Comment: No it is not. The problem is in the `function()` part, because if I change whatever I'm trying to do there, let's say change `innerHTML` of something, it will work. It seems that `style.fill-opacity` is not the right way.

Comment: Copy/paste that into your console; it is not syntactically correct, at least not as plain JavaScript.

Comment: This is being outputted by a php script correct?

Comment: Yes I am outputting this by PHP. The problem is clearly at the function() part because just now I have changed `style.fill-opacity: 0.5` to `style = 'fill: yellow'` and this works good but doesn't help me. Also, using `style = 'fill-opacity: 0.5'` clearly won't work because that's gonna be the whole style and I'm losing other properties.

Comment: `fill-opacity` is not a valid property name. Rather, it's a subtraction.

Comment: Alright, that was it. I changed `fill-opacity` to `fillOpacity` and now it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the semi-colon from your 0.5 fill-opacity

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I have changed it to `style.fillOpacity = '0.5'` and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @hydravink The semi-colon is not relevant for the "fix"